# GetResource, dynamic parent.

Tags: dynamic, parent-child, modx

my problem is the following. I'm currently making a blog-page with get-page, get-resources, form-it, and wayfinder. This question requires a decent amount of knowledge about Modx and snippits. I've got the page numberin and all working and i've got a template page with all my calls in it (called weblogTemplate). This template has the following wayfinder call in it :

```
[[!getResources? &parents=`5` &limit=`5` &tpl=`blogPost`]]
          [[!getPage?
             &elementClass=`modSnippet`
             &element=`getResources`

             &parents=`4`
             &depth=`2`
             &limit=`5`
             &pageNavOuterTpl=`[[+first]][[+prev]][[+pages]][[+next]][[+last]]`
             &pageVarKey=`page`
             &pageFirstTpl=`<li class="controlFirst"><a[[+classes]][[+title]] href="[[+href]]">Eerste pagina</a></li>`
             &pageLastTpl=`<li class="controlLast"><a[[+classes]][[+title]] href="[[+href]]">Laatste pagina</a></li>`
             &pagePrevTpl=`<li class="controlPrev"><a[[+classes]][[+title]] href="[[+href]]">&lt;&lt;</a></li>`
             &pageNextTpl=`<li class="controlNext"><a[[+classes]][[+title]] href="[[+href]]">&gt;&gt;</a></li>`

             &includeTVs=`1`
             &includeContent=`1`

             &tpl=`blogListPost`
          ]]
```

as you can see the parent is set here to id number 5. This is fine for the homepage but any child page connected in the blog page also uses the same template and so would also have the same menu as the parent. You could use a fix to simply create 1 template for a page and keep using a different getResource call but keep in mind that it is a blog im making, new pages keep getting added. The user can't (, and wouldn't even understand to) make a template and edit any code. A solution i thought of would be to make the parent id dynamic, so it adjust to whatever page it is currently on. So for example if it was on the page with id number 12 it would make the parent call set to 12 and so show all the content under id number 12. If anyone has any ideas / thoughts / solutions i would be very grateful to hear them.

[(a link about wayfinder that i used.)](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/Wayfinder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
[[!getPage?
                 &elementClass=`modSnippet`
                 &element=`getResources`

                 &parents=`[[*id]]`
                 &depth=`0`
                 &limit=`10`
                 &pageNavOuterTpl=`[[+first]][[+prev]][[+pages]][[+next]][[+last]]`
                 &pageVarKey=`page`
                 &pageFirstTpl=`<li class="controlFirst"><a[[+classes]][[+title]] href="[[+href]]">Eerste pagina</a></li>`
                 &pageLastTpl=`<li class="controlLast"><a[[+classes]][[+title]] href="[[+href]]">Laatste pagina</a></li>`
                 &pagePrevTpl=`<li class="controlPrev"><a[[+classes]][[+title]] href="[[+href]]">&lt;&lt;</a></li>`
                 &pageNextTpl=`<li class="controlNext"><a[[+classes]][[+title]] href="[[+href]]">&gt;&gt;</a></li>`

                 &includeTVs=`1`
                 &includeContent=`1`

                 &tpl=`blogListPost`
              ]]
```

Thanks to Vasis for the provided help.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to use two templates - one for main and one for the blog pages and use in blog templates:

```
&parents=`[[*id]]`
```

The problem with the user solveds by setting `default_template` in the system settings.

Comment: what should i do with depth now? If i set it to 1 it still shows all the pages.

Comment: use any depth, and just filter by template: `&where=\`{"template:=":8}`\`

Comment: i still dont exactly get your answer can you elaborate your answer via an example?

Comment: in blog template use: `[[!getResources? &parents=\`[[*id]]\` &where=\`{"template:=":8}\` &limit=\`5\` &tpl=\`blogPost\`]]` - changee 8 to your template id